# Grunt useminPrepare - not all CSS files are included in build (Yeoman)

Tags: build, gruntjs, yeoman

I have this in my index.html file:

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/flags.css" />
<!-- endbuild -->>
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
<!-- endbuild -->
```

So I am linking to 3 CSS files. When I run my grunt build script, which is based on Yeoman, I get my vendor.css and my main.css, but in the vendor.css the flags.css part is missing.

Here is the relevant part of my gruntfile.js:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},

// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
  }
},
```